# Accessing classes that are inside namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to learn the namespaces feature in PHP, however how do I access classes that are in namespaces?

Like, say I have the class `Users` inside the namespace called `Core`, how do I access that namespace from the `Pages` namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
<?php
$users = new \Core\Users;
echo $users->all();
```

When you want to use a class that's inside a namespace, you need to define the "absolute path" to the class, like I have done in the example. Note the `\` before the `Core` namespace, that tells PHP to use the `Core` namespace that is located in the root or "global" namespace of PHP.

So if you wanted to access the `Users` class in your `Pages` namespace, you would do the following:

```
<?php
namespace Pages;

$users = new \Core\Users;
echo $users->all();
```

There's also another way to use the `Users` class, which is:

```
<?php
namespace Pages;
use \Core\Users as Users;

$users = new Users;
echo $users->all();
```

The `use \Core\Users;` line allows you to use the `Users` class from the `Core` namespace as if it were a normal class inside the `Pages` namespace.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I was about to give up with the namespaces, totally confused my noob php mind. thank you.